# Product page redirects me at admin side. URL remains same

Tags: magento

when i click on product URL, it redirects me at admin dashboard but URL remain same? We have tried a lot but couldn't figure out. Is there something that I am missing. Do I need to check anything? 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a LOT more information to get some help Bharat.  Please start with information about your server and how you have it configured.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons redirect to admin dashboard:

1)Viewaction() in product controller (Mage/catalog/productcontroller) contain some redirect script.

2)Any custom module override the Product controller to override the original controller in Mage folder.

**Solution:** 
I have made the module that resolve your problem

1)create custom module :
Link[:http://brymayor.com/magento/magento-module-creator/]

KeshavSourav(package_name) ProductPage(modulename)

2)Add  the following  code in config  file  in  etc folder.

3)  Create the Product Controller in controller folder in your custom module

include_once('Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php'); 
class KeshavSourav_ProductPage_ProductController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

public function viewAction(){

```
       // Get initial data from request
    $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
    $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $specifyOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');

    // Prepare helper and params
    $viewHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view');

    $params = new Varien_Object();
    $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
    $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);




    // Render page
    try {
        $viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == $viewHelper->ERR_NO_PRODUCT_LOADED) {
            if (isset($_GET['store'])  && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_redirect('');
            } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_forward('noRoute');
            }
        } else {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }


}}
```

Answer (score 0):

config code:

```
    <routers>
       <keshavsourav_productpage>
           <use>standard</use>
           <args>
               <module>KeshavSourav_ProductPage</module>
               <frontName>test</frontName>
           </args>
       </keshavsourav_productpage>


     <catalog>
            <args>
                <modules>
<KeshavSourav_ProductPage before="Mage_Catalog">KeshavSourav_ProductPage</KeshavSourav_ProductPage>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </catalog>       
       </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <keshavsourav_productpage>
                <file>keshavsourav_productpage.xml</file>
            </keshavsourav_productpage>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```